# Getting Training from a reliable Australian PRINCE2 training provider

Tags: training, prince2

I'm looking for a reliable training provider in Australia for PRINCE2, preferably one that has flexible delivery (online/distance & face-to-face) training available and want to put together some good criteria for selecting one.

- Do I need to take the exam on-site with the trainer? This could be pricey travel-wise and is something I'd like to avoid.
- As far as other costs go, is there anything that is missing or other things I should take note of?

Comment: If you are willing to do online training why limit yourself to Australian providers? I'm in Canada and got very good service from a UK-based provider.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you have to sit the exams in-person, even if you do the study by distance/online. It didn't occur to me that some providers might have online exams, so maybe that's something I can check out!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to train with anyone world-wide. You do have to sit the exams in person, but the exams do NOT have to be proctored by the trainer. APMG group is the certification body and are the ones who arrange for the exams. If you wanted to you could buy the text book, self-study and then talk to APMG to set up an exam location and date.

Ensure that an online trainer includes sitting both the Foundation and Practitioner exams in their costs. It works out to about US$500 or thereabouts for each exam.

The website for the Australasian arm of APMG is on the web [here](http://www.apmg-international.com/apmg-australasia/home-aus.aspx). They should be able to provide you with more details about sitting the exams. If you are the first in your city to sit these exams you may need to help them find a facility that will agree to proctor the exams. Typically they use the local public library system. In my case they worked with a local community college.

For what it is worth I went through [Advantage Learning](http://www.advantagelearning.co.uk/), their non-EU online training costs are about A$1,250. Overall a good experience for me.